# If $x_n \to a$ and $x'_n \to a$, then $\{x_1, x'_1, x_2, x'_2, ...\} \to a$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I know that if all subsequences of $\{x_1, x'_1, x_2, x'_2, ...\}$ converge to $a$, then $\{x_1, x'_1, x_2, x'_2, ...\}$ converges to $a$, but I only know two subsequences of $\{x_1, x'_1, x_2, x'_2, ...\}$ that converge to $a$, namely $x_n$ and $x'_n$. How do I show that there don't exist any other subsequences that converge to something other than $a$?

Comment: for $x_n$ there exists some $n_1$, for $x'_n$, there exists some $n_2$, then for $\{x_1,x'_1,\ldots\}$ take $n_0>2n_1+2n_2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y=(x_1,x_1',x_2,x_2',...)$. For $n$ odd, we have $y_n = x_{n +1\over 2}$,
for $n$ even, we have $y_n = x_{n \over 2}'$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ then there are $N,N'$ such that if
$k \ge N$ we have $|a-x_k| < \epsilon$ and
if $k \ge N'$ we have $|a-x_k'| < \epsilon$.

Let $M = 2\max(N,N')$ and $n \ge M$. Then if $n$ is odd, we have
${n +1\over 2} \ge N$ and so $|y_n-a| < \epsilon$. Similarly, if $n$
is even, we have ${n \over 2}\ge N'$ and so $|y_n-a| < \epsilon$.

Hence $y_n \to a$.

Comment: Sorry for late +1 but yes, this is exactly what I would have done. It's almost a non-question because "but both get as close as one requires to $a$"

Comment: @copper.hat I am still having trouble understanding this proof. I don't understand why we need to let $M = 2\max(N, N')$. Say for some fixed $\epsilon$ that $N = 5$ and $N' = 10$. Then if we choose $M = \max(N, N')$, then we choose $N'$ and so since $N' > N$, both sequences converge past when $N'$. So why do we need the extra factor of $2$?

Comment: @morphic: The $N,N'$ come from considerations on $x_n,x_n'$, to 'convert' the $N,N'$ for use with $y_n$ you need to multiply by 2.

Comment: @copper.hat Does multiplying by 3 also work?

Comment: Multiplying the indices by any number $\ge 2$ will work. Remember the sequence is $(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4,...) = (x_1,x_1', x_2,x_2',...)$. The corresponding indices are $(1,2,3,4,...)$ and $(1,1,2,2,...).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Any convergent sequence is Cauchy. Then notice that every subsequence converging to $b\neq a$ implies that the sequence itself converges to $b$, which generates an absurd.

Answer (score 2):

Fix $\epsilon>0$ and take $N\in\mathbb N$ such that for every $n\ge N$, $|x_n-a|<\epsilon$ and $|x'_n-a|<\epsilon$. Now observe that for this epsilon the natural number $2N$ works.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

Use the following lemma:

> A sequence $\{a_n\}_n$ converges to $a$ iff every subsequence of $\{a_n\}_n$ admits a sub-subsequence that converges to $a$.

You can try to prove this lemma by your own, it's not difficult (look at the negation of the definition of *convergence*).

Please notice that the lemma you're trying to use is that a sequence converges to something iff every subsequence of it converges to the same something. The lemma I posted says something different.

---

Here I show you some details:

> We have to prove that any subsequence of $\{x_1, x'_1, x_2, x'_2, ...\}$ contains a sub-subsequence (i.e., a subsequence of the subsequence) that converges to $a$. Take an arbitrary subsequence of $\{x_1, x'_1, x_2, x'_2, ...\}$, two cases: it contains infinitely many elements from the sequence $\{x_n\}_n$ or it contains infinitely many elements from the sequence $\{x'_n\}_n$, does this give you an idea about how to get a sub-subsequence that converges to $a$?