# Sequence of differentiable,equicontinuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, arzela-ascoli, sequence-of-function

I got stuck the other day trying to tackle the following problem :

Let $ \left \{ f_n\left.  \right \} \right. $  be a sequence of differentiable functions : $ f_n \quad :  [0,1] \to \mathbb{R} $  with $ ||f'_n||_{\infty} \leq 1 $

Suppose  $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int^{1}_{0} f_n(x)g(x)dx=0  \quad (2)$$
For all continuous functions $ g:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}  $

Prove that $ f_n $ converges uniformly to $ 0 $ .

My progress so far is near trivial. I concluded using equicontinuity that it is sufficient to show pointwise convergence to some function $ f $ and then use dominated convergence to  $ (2) $  and then after some use of the problem's  linearity and weierstrass approximation theorem  with polynomials  conclude that $$ f {\equiv } 0 $$  .

I also got a trivial bound on $$ ||f_{n}||_{\infty} \leq \frac{1}{2} $$ ( if i didn't make any mistakes in calculations )  using the fact that $$ (f_n(x)-x)' \leq 0 $$ and $$ (f_{n}(x)+x)' \geq 0 $$

I can also obtain a uniformly convergent subsequence to $ 0 $ using Arzela-Ascoli but that doesn't seem to help much.

I would prefer , a slight/mild  hint to point me to the right direction , rather than a complete solution .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure the bound $\Vert f_n\Vert_\infty\le \frac12$ is correct. The sequence of constant functions $f_n(x)=\frac4n$ satisfies all your hypotheses.
Take $g=1$ and use the mean value theorem to find $x_n\in [0,1]$ such that $f_n(x_n)=\int_0^1f_n(x)\,dx\to 0$.  Using this and the bounds on the derivatives, you can prove that the sequence is equibounded and equi-integrable and then use Ascoli-Arzela. Is this a sufficient hint? It is not clear on where you are stuck.

**Edit**
Start from a subsequence $f_{n_k}$. Using Ascoli-Arzela you can find a durther subsequence $f_{n_{k_j}}$ which converges uniformly to some function $f$. Now use Weierstrass approximation theorem with polynomials to show that $f=0$.
Hence, for **every** subsequence $f_{n_k}$ you can find a further subsequence $f_{n_{k_j}}$ which converges uniformly to $0$. This implies that the original sequence must converge uniformly to zero.

I am using a general fact about sequences in metric spaces. See the lemma in the link [sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1275913/if-x-n-to-a-and-x-n-to-a-then-x-1-x-1-x-2-x-2-to-a/1275915#1275915)

Comment: I agree that the bound might be wrong . On the other hand we can bound $f_n $ somehow with the same method . But the use of Arzela-Ascoli will only give me a sub-sequence that converges uniformly . I got stuck proving that $ f_n $ converges pointwise

Comment: OK, so the problem is that you have a subsequence and not the entire sequence? I  edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks . I think , considering your edit , one can suppose that the original sequence doesn't converge to $ 0 $ with the sup norm and then construct a sequence such that $ ||f_{n_k}||_{\infty} \geq \epsilon $ (1)  and then use arzela-ascoli to obtain a subsequence of $ f_{n_k} $ namely $ f_{n_{k_m}} $ such that $ ||f_{n_{k_m}}||_{\infty} \to 0 $  which of course leads to a contradiction due to (1) .

Comment: yes, this is the proof.

Answer (score 0):

This is a "manual" solution to prove the pointwise convergence. I think one can skip the first two steps by taking 
$g$ to be a hat function.

- Show that there is a constant $M$ such that $\lVert f_n \rVert_\infty \leq M$ for all $n$.
- Show that we have in fact
  $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int^{1}_{0} f_n(x)g(x)dx=0$$
  for any $g \in L^1([0,1])$. (use a sequence $g_k$ of continuous functions that converges to $g$ in $L^1([0,1])$).
- Let $\varepsilon >0$, $a\in (0,1)$ and $g=1_{(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)}$ for $\varepsilon$ small enough. Prove that $f_n(a) \leq 2\varepsilon$ for $n$ large enough.